# Получить все строки, кроме последней

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = '123\n456\n789'
```

Как из строки 'a' получить только 123456?

Comment: Для начала опишите хотя бы, чем именно символы `123456` отличаются от всех остальных (применительно к вашей задаче).

Answer (score 4):

[срез](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html)

```
''.join('123\n456\n789'.split('\n')[:-1])
```

rsplit

```
'123\n456\n789'.rsplit('\n', 1)[0].replace('\n', '')
```

rfind

```
s = '123\n456\n789'
i = s.rfind('\n', 1)
s[:i].replace('\n', '')
```

Comment: Надо еще ``\n`` из середины удалить.